# What is the issue with this following PFQuery block?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I've been getting the `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11` error and it pinpoints an error in the range of following statement:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
                    query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
                    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: usernameTxt.text!)
                    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
                            if error == nil {

                            if (objects!.count > 0){

                                if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).signUpOn {
                                    // present alert view
                                }

                            } else {

                                print("Username is available.")

                            }

                        } else {

                            print("error")

                        }

                    }
```

Is there any error in this statement? I've also been advised that this error is an Xcode bug and can error out a perfectly fine statement, and that I should separate the code.. so its a two part question, is there an issue as it is? and how do I separate it if so?

Comment: comment out the `whereKey:equalTo:`  if that fixes it, then I'd suspect an unset outlet on the usernameTxt object.

Answer (score 0):

Change `(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?)` to `(objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?)`.

Took me ages to find this answer on Parse, but it worked. Spent the whole day fixing my queries. At least I learned refactoring is important.